# When user touches and moves his finger, how to get which elements (vms) were touched with knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, touch

I'm using knockout and I'm trying to achieve is this:

I want the user to select some blocks:

1. click the first block (it is selected)
2. without releasing the mouse button, move the mouse around
3. every block you pass through is selected
4. release the button to stop selecting.

It's very easy to do it using mouse events, but I need to target touch devices too (android, iphone, touch notebooks).

How to have the same behavior using touch events with knockout?

1. touch the first block
2. without releasing the finger, move around
3. select all touched blocks
4. release the finger

ps: I got stuck because when using touch events, the event source is locked to the first touched element (oh god, why???) and I can't figure out which others blocks the user touches.

Here is a jsfiddle with my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/m38tfpq4/2/

```js
var vmBlock = function(label) {
  var self = this;
  self.text = label;
  self.color = ko.observable('grey');
}

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.isSelecting = false;
  self.blocks = [new vmBlock('a'), new vmBlock('b'), new vmBlock('c')];
  self.selectStart = function(block) {
    console.log('start');
    self.isSelecting = true;
    self.select(block);
  }
  self.selectEnd = function(block) {
    console.log('end');
    self.isSelecting = false;
  }
  self.select = function(block) {
    console.log('select: ' + self.isSelecting);
    if (!self.isSelecting) {
      return;
    }
    block.color('red');
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: blocks">
  <div class="block" onselectstart="return false" data-bind="text: text, style:{ 'background-color' : color }, event: { mousedown: $parent.selectStart, mouseover: $parent.select, mouseup: $parent.selectEnd }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your js fiddle is empty

Comment: @AdamWolski Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* use [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint), but I can't imagine it's the best/only way...

Feels hacky and slow, since it first uses the `x` and `y` of a `touch` to pinpoint an element, and then uses `ko.dataFor` to get to the `block` viewmodel... It *does* work though...

An interim solution could be to store a block `id` property in an attribute on the element, and keep a `Map` linking `id` props to `block` viewmodels in your `$parent` vm. Might speed up some parts of the logic.

I'm curious to see if anyone else comes up with a more logical way of linking those weird touch events to an element :)

**To test this snippet, set your developer tools to [emulate touches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MV4Vx.png)**

```js
var vmBlock = function(label) {
  var self = this;
  self.text = label;
  self.color = ko.observable('grey');
}

var vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.isSelecting = false;
  self.blocks = [new vmBlock('a'), new vmBlock('b'), new vmBlock('c')];
  
  self.select = function(block) {
    block.color("red");
  };
  
  self.startTouch = function(data, event) {
    self.isSelecting = true;
  };
  
  self.endTouch = function(data, event) {
    self.isSelecting = false;
  };
  
  self.touch = function(data, event) {
    if (!self.isSelecting) return;
    
    var x = event.touches[0].clientX;
    var y = event.touches[0].clientY;
    var target = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    var vm = ko.dataFor(target);
    if (vm && vm.color) self.select(vm);
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

```css
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: blocks, event: {
                                    touchstart: startTouch,
                                    touchend: endTouch,
                                    touchmove: touch
                                  }">
  <div class="block" onselectstart="return false" data-bind="text: text, style:{ 'background-color' : color }">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice catch! I also feel it's not the best solution, but there are so many hacky solutions to common problems in javascript that I wouldn't be surprised if using elementFromPoint was the best approach.